# can we "discover that the house will have been haunted"?

Tags: complements, content-clauses

Are the following sentences grammatical?

> They will discover that the house will have been haunted.
>
> They discover that the house will have been haunted.
>
> They discovered that the house will have been haunted.

Comment: They're all grammatically correct, but unlikely usages.  The phrase "the house will have been haunted" means that at some point in the future,  somebody looking back could say "the house *has been* haunted".  That's simply a statement of fact.  You could discover that fact now, or in the future, or have discovered it in the past.  But all of them seem like unlikely ways to phrase something.  It might help if you explained the situation you're trying to describe.

Comment: Not trying to *describe* a situation. I'm wanting to know if the future perfect construction is valid there.

Comment: It is syntactically correct, yes.

Comment: I wouldn't object to this construction: *"By tomorrow, they will have discovered that the house is / has been haunted."* Your examples require too much brain thought, but No.3 sounds more plausible.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A. Thanks for correcting the typo.Do you also have spleen-thoughts?  :)

Comment: My guts tells me that the sentences are awkward, and their meanings difficult to decipher. if there was slightly more context, the task would be easier.

Comment: No context.  Can a future perfect construction in an English *that*-clause complement the verb **discover** in any tense?

Comment: The only relevant times are (1) when the house was haunted, and (2) when they made the discovery. Since (1) clearly must precede (2), I see no possible real-world additional or different meaning that could be imparted by playing around with complex nonsensical tenses - at some point in the future they'll find that *the house **was** haunted*, so that's what they will discover.

Comment: I'm sorry, don't get annoyed but I have to paraphrase: *"The house will have been haunted when / by the time they discover it."* *That* makes sense!

Comment: @Mari-Lou A. I'm not asking how to say it in a better way. My question is about the grammar of those constructions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: so you're saying the future perfect construction in the that-clause is ungrammatical, and must be replaced with a finite past, **was**?

Comment: @TRomano: I'm not sure what you might mean by "ungrammatical". Your example usage is certainly "unidiomatic, unnecessary, confusing" and arguably the actual *logic* of the intended temporal relationships is unsound. Whether you ***must*** replace ***will have been*** with ***was*** is another question. Your specific example raises big problems for me on the semantic front, but I have no real difficulty with, say, *You should have your car serviced regularly, otherwise when you eventually pass it on to your son, he'll find that it won't have been maintained as well as he might have liked*.

Comment: (Although in practice obviously *...find that it **wasn't** maintained* would be almost infinitely more likely.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'm asking specifically if a future perfect construction in a that-clause is a viable complement for **discover**.

Comment: I suppose by "viable" you mean something halfway between "grammatical" and "idiomatic", but I'm not sure how useful it is to go down to that level of detail. For all practical purposes I would say it should be enough to just note that such convoluted tense usages would almost always be "undesirable".

Comment: Whenever I hear or read sentences like these I remember Sheldon, Leonard and Raj.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly.

"The house will have been haunted" is obviously grammatical: it uses a passive-voice form of "to haunt" conjugated into the perfect and preceded by the modal verb "will," which indicates the future.

"They will discover/discover/discovered that" are also all grammatical. The choice between them is governed by the time of the discovery: future, non-past, or past. Since the time of discovery is logically unrelated to the time when the house will have been haunted, any of them can combine with "The house will have been haunted" to form a grammatical sentence. "[Backshifting](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/sentence/reported-speech-backshift.htm)" in English is not required if a situation is still true. So as long as the house has still not been haunted yet at the time you say the sentence, it's perfectly fine to say "They discovered that the house will have been haunted," using a past-tense verb in the main clause and the non-past modal "will" in the dependent clause.

Maybe it will be clearer if we insert specific times (which I don't believe changes the grammaticality of any of the sentences):

1. At 3:00 tomorrow, they will discover that the house will have been
   haunted by the time the new residents move in.
2. In episode 2 of "Garage Ghost Hunters", they discover that the house will have been haunted by the time the new residents move in.
3. At 3:00 yesterday, they discovered that the house will have been
   haunted by the time the new residents move in.

If you find the preceding sentences grammatical, I don't see any way you can find the following sentences ungrammatical:

4. They will discover that the house will have been haunted.
5. They discover that the house will have been haunted.
6. They discovered that the house will have been
   haunted.

Comment: You're saying all three versions are acceptable, as they stand, without being modified in the slightest. Because that is what the OP is asking.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Yeah, that's what my I was trying to say.

Comment: But you added the time expression "by the time" which is absent from the original examples. Of course your modified examples make more sense.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: My point was meant to be that they make more sense, but the grammar of the verb tenses is the same.